# substring IP address in java

Tags: java, substring

This program takes string like that 192.168.1.125 and cut every number then converts it to integer, but it returns an error.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Number;
import java.lang.Integer;
class Ip
{
   public static void main ( String [] args )
   {

      int i ;
      i = args[0].indexOf ( '.' );
      do
      {
         if ( i != -1 )
            args[0].substring ( 0, i );
         String str = args[0].substring ( i + 1, args[0].length() );
         String str2 = Integer.parseInt ( str );
         System.out.println ( str2 );
      }
      while ( i != -1 );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` returns an integer, not a string (it's entire point is to create an integer):

```
String str2 = Integer.parseInt ( str );
```

Note, the compiler gave an error and you should have tried to figure out what it tells you:

```
Ip.java:16: incompatible types
found   : int
required: java.lang.String
         String str2 = Integer.parseInt ( str );
```

Answer (score 1):

#### On `parseInt`

`parseInt` takes a `String` and returns an `int`. Here's a simple example of using the method:

```
    int num = Integer.parseInt("42");
    System.out.println(num == 42); // prints "true"
```

#### API references

- [`int parseInt(String s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

  - **Parameters:** `s` - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
  - **Returns:** the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.

---

As for your problem, the simplest solution is to use a `java.util.Scanner`

```
     import java.util.*;
     //...

     Scanner sc = new Scanner("192.168.1.125").useDelimiter("\\.");
     int[] parts = new int[] {
         sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()
     };
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
     // prints "[192, 168, 1, 125]"
```

The only non-straightforward part of this is the `\\.`, which is how you write `\.` as a String literal in Java. The reason why you need the `\` is because `useDelimiter` takes a regex, and in regex dot `.` is a metacharacter, so you need to escape it to match a literal dot.

#### API references

- [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

Answer (score 0):

You're discarding the result of the first substring, and assigning an integer to a string (as noted by Klatchko).  Also, you can simplify if you use a for loop, since IPv4 addresses always have 4 components.  This assumes you can't use [String.split](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or similar.